# String array gets every character input instead of full word?

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist, android-edittext

I have a logical error in my code below that produces the following result when an array-list `personArray` is printed out in my `Activity_2`:

**Scenario:**

If the user types their name as **"John"** in the `EditText` field `name` it will get added to the `personArray` array-list.  Then it will get passed into my `Activity_2` where it is printed out.

However, upon doing so the print out is this:

**[J, Jo, Joh, John]**

It's the same for my other `EditText` fields.  I just want to add the **whole** word to my `personArray` and **not** every character as I typed it in.

My variables:

```
ArrayList<String> personArray = new ArrayList<>;
EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
```

My `Text Changed Listener` inside my `onCreate()` in `Activity_1`:

```
name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i1, int i2){
      //it's supposed to add the user's FULL name input to personArray
      //however it ends up adding EVERY character input instead
      personArray.add(name.getText().toString().trim()); 
   }
});

// repeat code for input for address, country, etc.
```

And my `Intent` inside my button click to go to my next `Activity_2`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_1.this, Activity_2.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("person", personArray);
startActvity(intent);
```

And getting the personArray string array in `Activity_2`:

```
final List<String> personList = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("person");
TextView txtPerson = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPerson);
txtPerson.setText(personList);
```

I'm not sure where to place my `personArray.add(name.getText().toString().trim());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the code in

```
@Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
 // do stuff 
}
```

**UPDATE**
Or you can get the whole input by using focus.

```
myEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() { 
@Override public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) { 
            if (!hasFocus) {
             String editTextInput = myEditText.getText().toString();
             }

     } 
    });
```

Comment: I already attempted that, and adding the code in beforeTextChanged() (separately) as well and it still produced the same result.

Comment: Thanks, this solution was more dynamic than what I had initially planned to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should use any character(For example comma / $ whatever ) or New Line key or Done key as the separator. Keep the hint for users that they input each new name with any character or new Line key.

So Your logic work will in onTextChanged method

```
 @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i1, int i2){
       if(s.equals(",") or check new Line or Done key character)
       {
         personArray.add(name.getText().toString().trim()); 
         name.setText("");
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the docs for [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html), the `onTextChanged` method is called whenever the text is changed. This means that this function will be called **anytime** the user changes the text. This includes typing in "J" "o" "h" and "n" when inputting the name "John".

This is why in your `Activity_2` you're seeing the output as [J, Jo, Joh, John]. This just means the `TextWatcher` is doing what it's supposed to do.

Instead of watching every edit of every edit text you should instead grab the text from your form (and validate it) before launching your intent.

```
void validateDataAndLaunchActivity() {

    String name = name.getText().toString().trim();
    // get the rest of the inputs
    // .. validate the input...
    ArrayList<String> personArray = new ArrayList<>();
    // insert items into your array and launch intent
    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_1.this, Activity_2.class);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("person", personArray);
    startActvity(intent);
}
```